# Using the Firebug console

Tags: javascript, firebug

I have added Firebug in my browser. Why am I getting the output as undefined when I type the following in the terminal of Firebug?

```
console.log('Testing console');
```

I was expecting the text "Testing console" to appear.

And also, I have installed Firebug light in Chrome. How do I get the search box?

Answer (score 0):

You should see both:

```
> console.log('Testing console');
"Testing console"
undefined
```

`console.log` logs to the console, but doesn't return a value.

Comment: I am not seeing Testing console in my case

Comment: What if you just type `'Testing console'`, does it echo?

Comment: Ok this is how I am getting. When I use console.log("XX") in some sites it echoes whereas in some sites it doesn’t. Are there any specific reason for this?

Comment: And 'Testing console' echoes fine

Answer (score 0):

Try with

First type this

```
var testingString = 'Testing Console'
```

you will get `undefined`

later type this.

```
console.log(testingString)
```

you will get `'Testing Console'`

But, why you get always `undefined`?

Well this is what happened first it runs `testingString` which return `"testing console"` string and followed it return value of `console.log()`, which is `"undefined"`.

If you don't want to get 'undefined' just type

```
"Testing console"
```

Hope you get the idea.